# How to foward all cookies with the AWS Cloudfront Module from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws, cdn

How can i set cookies in the AWS Cloudfront Module i cant find anything in the offical Documentation from AWS Terraform Module

```
module "cdn" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudfront/aws"

  ordered_cache_behavior = [
    {
      path_pattern           = "/wp-admin/*"
      target_origin_id       = "loadbalancer"
      viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"

      allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
      headers         = ["*"]
      forward_cookies = "all"
      compress        = true
      query_string    = true
    },


    {
      path_pattern           = "/wp-login.php/"
      target_origin_id       = "loadbalancer"
      viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"

      allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
      headers         = ["*"]
      forward_cookies = "all"
      compress        = true
      query_string    = true
    }
  ]
```

i tryed diffrent approches like set

```
cookies[*]
forward_cookies = "all"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "all"
      }
    }
```

When i run it i dont get any error but it set in Cloudfront anything to none. The same happens when i try to set any cookies. Did someone have a Solution to the Problem or should i use the offical ressources.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudfront/blob/master/main.tf), it appears you need to specify `cookies_forward = "all"`, instead of `forward_cookies`. Like this:

```
  ordered_cache_behavior = [
    {
      path_pattern           = "/wp-admin/*"
      target_origin_id       = "loadbalancer"
      viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"

      allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
      headers         = ["*"]
      cookies_forward = "all"
      compress        = true
      query_string    = true
    },
```

Comment: Still dont work but thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: It looks like you also need to have `use_forwarded_values = true` in order to enable forwarding anything, in addition to `cookies_forward = "all"`

Comment: Still dont work D:

Comment: Is it showing any changes at all in your Terraform plan? This terraform module is one of the worst documented modules I've ever seen. You have to view the source code to use it. And it only creates a few resources. I would personally just work directly with the Terraform AWS resources instead of using this module.

Comment: I didnt show any changes at all! Yeah the documentation is pretty bad. And i think i will switch to the AWS resources instead using this module. Thanks again for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `cookies_forward = "all"` attribute, you could use a **Cache Policy** specifying not to cache cookies.

To achieve that, you could either use one of the default cache policies provided by AWS like this:

```
data "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "caching_disabled" {
  name = "Managed-CachingDisabled"
}
```

And then set it within one of your `ordered_cache_behavior` blocks like this:

```
  ordered_cache_behavior = [
    {
      ...
      cache_policy_id = data.aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.caching_disabled.id
      ...
    }
```

Or you can create your own, like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "forward_all_cookies" {
  name        = "Forward-All-Cookies"
  comment     = "Policy with cookie caching disabled"
  default_ttl = 0
  max_ttl     = 0
  min_ttl     = 0
  parameters_in_cache_key_and_forwarded_to_origin {
    cookies_config {
      cookie_behavior = "none"
    }
    headers_config {
      header_behavior = "none"
    }
    query_strings_config {
      query_string_behavior = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

And then set it within one of your `ordered_cache_behavior` blocks like this:

```
  ordered_cache_behavior = [
    {
      ...
      cache_policy_id = aws_cloudfront_cache_policy.forward_all_cookies
      ...
    }
```

---

Further reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html